# Conceptual dobuts about EFTs and the decoupling of heavy fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, beyond-the-standard-model, effective-field-theory

I've tried to synthetize some of my misconceptions in the following statements. I just like to know which of them are true and get some intution about them.

1. EFTs exist only if heavy fields decouple (i.e. we cannot integrate out heavy fields that do not decouple).
2. If a theory has beta functions and form factors of n-point functions without heavy fields in the external legs go like $M^k$ (with $k<0$), this signals the decoupling of heavy fields (with mass $M$).
3. If there is "theory A" at low energies and "theory B" at high energies, we can always make a matching between both energy regimes no matter if the theavy fields decouple.
4. The previous statement is True because the matching conditions are just a statement on the continuity of the beta functions, and this can be ensured no matter if the beta functions grow or shrink with powers of $M$.

To my understanding, 1 is False and the other ones are True. Yet, I'm not so sure about it. If this is so, what's the big deal with the decoupling theorem when dealing with the top quark in the $Z^0$ or $W_\mu^\pm$ propagators, or in the $Z\rightarrow b\overline{b}$ effective vertex?. Apparently, the literature says that one should not integrate it out because these objects grow as $m_t^2$ (it doesn't decouple), but does this mean that we cannot integrate out fields that do not decouple, in general?.